# Transfer files and run commands to/on remote servers, are there light weight tools

Tags: configuration, remote-access, file-transfer, tooling, synctool

I tried **synctool**, it can run simple command on remote "nodes", such as "date", "hostname".  But it failed to sync itself ("masterdir") to nodes/host.

```
$synctool
...... can not mkdir on node1 ... or something ...
```

Beside "**puppet, chef**", is there any **light weight tools** to do the job? Simply basic configuration managements, transfer files, and remote commands execution.

There is a perl tool "LCFG", but I can not find any thing about it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use standard SSH/sftp?

Comment: Yes, puppet, chef, ..., or script it myself, what's the other way?  Accept your answer anyway.